# what does `python -m pip install` do?

Tags: python, pip

I have recently encountered a repo which has instructions to install the requirements via:

```
python -m pip install -r ..
```

I have always used just:

```
pip3 install -r ..
```

What is the difference between the two? Which is correct (if there is such a thing)?

Comment: If you have multiple python executables, the first ensures that the specified python executable has the package installed.

Comment: I think there is a small typo in your question. It should be ```pip3 install -r ```.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are basically synonymous; on some platforms the latter won't always work for various reasons.

Comment: ah right, thank you for your insight. accepted your answer :)